# How to include .js file in google app engine project

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jsp

I have a .jsp page as the frontend of my app.  I need to include a seperate .js file in that page.

my directories look like this

```
src
|--->com.stuff
     |--->servlet.java
war
|-->WEB-INF
    |--->pages
         |---->page.jsp
               include.js
```

From my java servlet I call

```
RequestDispatcher jsp = req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/page.jsp");
```

which works fine but in page.jsp I have this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="./include.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried a few differnet things in place of "./include.js" and I always get an error from firebug saying

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8888/include.js"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the docs on "Using Static Files"  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles

You should!

It explicitly states "By default, App Engine makes all files in the WAR available as static files except JSPs and files in WEB-INF/."

And your `include.js` is inside `WEB-INF/`